# Java FX редактирование кортежа в таблице при совпадении одного атрибута

Tags: java, javafx, таблицы

Имеются объявления:

```
    public TableColumn<sample.Dev, String> Num;
    public TableColumn<Dev, String> Nam;
    public TableColumn<Dev, String> Adr;
    public TableColumn<Dev, String> Pow;
    public TableColumn<Dev, String> Tim;
    public ToggleButton Find;
private ObservableList<Dev> DevD = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Инициализация:

```
        Num.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dev, String>("number"));
        Nam.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dev, String>("name"));
        Adr.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dev, String>("ardess"));
        Pow.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dev, String>("power"));
        Tim.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dev, String>("time"));
```

Добавление кортежа:

```
DevD.add(new Dev(String.valueOf(Ni)+"."+String.valueOf(NDi), A[j].substring(19), A[j].substring(0,16), String.valueOf(LQIi).substring(0,5)+" %", time.substring(10, 20)));
```

Класс Dev.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Dev {
   private final SimpleStringProperty number;
    private final SimpleStringProperty name;
    private final SimpleStringProperty ardess;
    private final SimpleStringProperty power;
    private final SimpleStringProperty time;

    public Dev(String number, String name, String ardess, String power, String time) {
        this.number = new SimpleStringProperty(number);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.ardess = new SimpleStringProperty(ardess);
        this.power = new SimpleStringProperty(power);
        this.time = new SimpleStringProperty(time);
    }


    public String getNumber(){
        return number.get();
    }
    public void setNumber(String value){
        number.set(value);
    }
    public SimpleStringProperty numberProperty() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name.get();
    }
    public void setName(String value){
        name.set(value);
    }
    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getArdess(){
        return ardess.get();
    }
    public void setArdess(String value){
        ardess.set(value);
    }
    public SimpleStringProperty ardessProperty() {
        return ardess;
    }

    public String getPower(){
        return power.get();
    }
    public void setPower(String value){
        power.set(value);
    }
    public SimpleStringProperty powerProperty() {
        return power;
    }

    public String getTime(){
        return time.get();
    }
    public void setTime(String value){
        time.set(value);
    }
    public SimpleStringProperty timeProperty() {
        return time;
    }


}
```

В общем сейчас значения просто добавляются, но хочется, чтобы при поступлении нового кортежа при совпадении атрибута A[j].substring(0,16) с одним из имеющихся в таблице, он не добавлялся, а перезаписывался полностью заменяя старую строку в таблице (может бы пусть и добавлялся, но удалял старую строку с таким же атрибутом)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищем индекс строки. Если мы нашли, то заменяем, иначе добавляем. Вам осталось лишь определить метод `isSame(Dev another)` в вашем классе `Dev`. Этот метод возвращает `true`, если по Вашим признакам пришедший `Dev` похож на текущий

```
Dev newDev = ; //
int rowNumber = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < tableView.getItems().size(); i++) {
    Dev dev = tableView.getItems().get(i);
    if (newDev.isSame(dev)) {
        rowNumber = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (rowNumber == -1) { //нет совпадений
    tableView.getItems().add(newDev);
} else {
    tableView.getItems().set(rowNumber, newDev);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло, ток не стал метод делать, сразу в if добавил проверку if (newDev.getArdess().equals(dev.getArdess()))